# What is System V in Ubuntu

Tags: 15.10

I'm very new to ubuntu and I want to develop in this excellent platform!
But this is quite different from windows ehehe.
Well, I searched some IDE's for php, css, html and more and i came across Geany.
I downloaded the tar and extrated it and in the installation steps, the first one is:

1. `cd` to the directory containing the package's source code and type
    `./configure` to configure the package for your system.  If you're
    using `csh` on an old version of System V, you might need to type
    `sh ./configure` instead to prevent `csh`' from trying to execute
    `configure` itself.

I don't know what is System V and I cannot find info about it. I searched Like System V Ubuntu and other variants but can't find info about it.
In general are problems or so and I cannot get the context.

Can someone explaine the System V role in Ubuntu and some documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[System V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_System_V) refers to one of the versions of the [original AT&T Unix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJlz0JIbHt8) all the way back from the 80s. Some software is configured to run on multiple platform and that's what Geany apparently does.

On the other hand, you didn't necessarily need to build it from source, because Geany is available through official repositories in Ubuntu. You can either open Software Center and find it there, or you can open terminal and run

```
sudo apt-get install geany
```

**Side-note**: System V may not be as prevalent these days, but it had really big influence on the world of Unix and Linux in general. For instance, many Linux distributions use same style of starting processes through the System V style of `init` scripts. Ubuntu also did so  prior to 6.10 release of Ubuntu; 6.10 featured new upstart system. Now as of 14.10 Ubuntu is switching to `systemd` , which is totally different. But in short, the System V really had big influence on the Unix and Linux world

Answer (score 1):

From the question it is obvious that the user is new to Ubuntu/Linux. I remember my time therefore the simple answer is:

Start Ubuntu Software Center. It is on left side of screen (see image)

In the search bar at Software Center type "Geany" without quotes and you will be presented with:

[image: See Image]

Click Install and happy programming.